How to make a Sticky header in Elementor Pro appear in front of all elements?
I have a menu header that is set as a sticky header - ( motion effects > sticky ).
On every post, I have a table of contents also set as "sticky".
When scrolling down, the menu overlays everything (expected) but not the table of contents widget.
How to fix this issue?


Z Index (z-index) is a CSS property that defines the order of overlapping HTML elements. Elements with a higher index will be placed on top of elements with a lower index.

from z-index-in-css-what-it-is-and-what-it-does
Using the z-index value you can set this property to appear on top of everything else on the site.
Setting it to a larger number than other properties will result in appearing in front of all elements on the site.
